# Javascript variable within a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have php function that checks if an entry exists in my database that I call with `class::checkThis($my_entry);`

In my script javascript is used to determined the name of the folder I am selecting, so $my_entry is supposed to look like this :

*(in normal is determined by php and the part in bold is what is determined by javascript)*

> C:/library/user/apatik/**folder1**

As you guess I can't find a working way to mix up thoses languages, and I don't really have any experience in javascript yet to figure out this.

The php code that returns the first part of the path is simply `$_SESSION['cwd'].'/'` and the javascript variable that returns the selected folder's name is `data_name` and is determined by `var data_name = $(this).attr('data-name');`

Is there a way to get something like `if (class::checkThis($_SESSION['cwd'].'/'.data_name) == true)` ?

None of what I tried so far worked and I'm having troubles finding an alternative.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm assuming your script is running on a webpage?  Or are you doing node or something?

Comment: indeed the script is running on a webpage (in wamp actually), I never heard of node tho.

Comment: Then your going to have to provide the value to your script as part of a request either by a form submit, ajax request, or normal page navigation as a key value pair.

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately I am not sure if I can use a request in my case, since the purpose of my function is to display an element or not regarding if the function returned true or not, so I don't know if I can have the page to refresh, I'll look into your suggestions anyways, thanks

Comment: Using an ajax request would allow you to get the information needed without a page reload.  The main point here is that php executes on the server.  Javascript, normally, runs on the client.  By the time that a user is executing your javascript, the php has finished.  To access information, it has to be available when it is running.

Comment: I understand, thanks !

Comment: Also I would like to say.  I hope you are doing some form of input cleaning as you are allowing an input variable to match directly to your server file system.  This can be a security concern.  It would most likely be better to provide a mapped key to the script that then looks up the directory in an associative array containing valid key value mappings.  That way should the user provide one that is not in that map, you remove the risk of them accessing data that they otherwise should not have had access to.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I don't have any knowledges on security yet (besides the basic in html forms and the basic php function to secure inputs), fortunately I'm only working on local for now, to learn. However the informations my function is comparing are in a dedicated table, and it compares the entries the same way a database would compare a new username on user's registration (to check if the username doesn't already exist) so hopefully it is safe enough ? I don't have the knowledges to build mapped keys yet, but I'll look into this when it's time :) thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make an AJAX request to accomplish this. You'll load the page as normal, except for the dynamic part. Then you can populate the dynamic part (I've illustrated it as `#content` here) based on the result of the AJAX call:

```
var data_name = $(this).attr('data-name');

...

$.ajax('http://example.com/my_php_script.php?data_name=' + data_name)
    .done(function(data){
        // "data" is the resulting output of the PHP script
        $('#content').append(data);
});
```

*NOTE:* The solution above uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Then, in your `my_php_script.php`, you can do something like this:

```
if (class::checkThis($_SESSION['cwd'] . '/' . $_GET['data_name']) == true) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems to match @Taplar's suggestion, I'll try this out and update !

Answer (score 0):

Ajax jQuery is your best solution.
This one using post method with event, just for reference...

```
<a href="#" class="anchor" data-name="folder1">Am I exist?</a>
<a href="#" class="anchor" data-name="folder2">Am I exist too?</a>

$('.anchor').click(function(){

    var data_name = "name=" + $(this).attr('data-name');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "is_exist.php",
        data: data_name,
        success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.response);
        }
    });
};
```

**is_exist.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $data['response'] = class::checkThis($_SESSION['cwd'].'/'.$_POST['name']) == true ? "exist" : "buried";
    echo json_encode($data);
```

}